# django 1.10 csrf_token not creating hidden input field

Tags: python, django, csrf

Есть лендинг с формой в которой не создаётся скрытое поле -

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="80NGejzAPl2aCbEEuyLqIT3ppMTJLilY">
```

Когда пробую отправить форму - ошибка 403, CSRF token missing or incorrect. После сабмита должно возвращаться на главную страницу.

Вот мой код:

html

```
<form class="get-info" action="{% url 'callback:send_callback' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %} ... </form>
```

middleware

```
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
```

views.py

```
from django.core.mail import BadHeaderError, send_mail
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, request
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.template.context_processors import csrf
from django.contrib import messages

def callback(request):
    phone = request.POST.get('phone', None)
    lastpath = request.POST.get('lastpath', None)
    if validatePhone(phone):
        if sendMail(phone):
            messages.success(request, 'Мы скоро перезвоним Вам')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(lastpath)
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Ошибка в отправке запроса. Попробуйте позже.')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(lastpath)
    else:
        messages.error(request, "Неверный формат номера телефона. Телефон нужно вводить в формате +99999999999")
        args = {}
        zzz = lastpath.render(RequestContext(request, args))
        return HttpResponse(zzz)
```

url формы -

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^callback/', views.callback, name='send_callback'),
]
```

Рендериг формы:

```
<form class="get-info" action="/callback/callback/" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_subject" value="karpaty-perezvonite-mne">
    <input id="callback" name="phone" type="tel" class="form-control"    placeholder="+ 380 ___-__-__">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="lastpath" value="/" style="display: none">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Send">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

При отправке формы получаю такую ошибку [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что говорит трейсбек? Что у вас в `lastpath`?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос как можно более полный трейсбек (там должны быть номера строк с ошибками). 

Я впервые вижу синтаксис вида `zzz = "/".render(...)` - так работает?

Comment: А со стороны js - Вы настроили возможность отправлять данные на сервер? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/#ajax

Comment: Проблема была в рендеринге главного шаблона. Спасибо.